# Determine if T can be diagonalized (in $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R $)

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $\ T: \mathbf R^3 \rightarrow \mathbf R^3 \ \ T(x,y,z) = (3x, 2y-5z, y-2z) $ for every $\ (x,y,z) \in \mathbf R^3 $

I need to find if T can be diagonalised 
So basically I know I'm looking for $\ Tv - I_3\lambda = 0 $

$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 2 & -5 \\\ 0 & 1 & - 2 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 0 & 0\\ 0 & \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 - \lambda & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2-\lambda & -5 \\ 0 & 1 & -2 -\lambda \end{bmatrix}$

and the determinant of this matrix will be $\ (3- \lambda)(\lambda^2 + 1) =0  $ we have only one eigenvalue of $\mathbb R $ which is 3 and the eigen vector will be $\ Sp \{(1,0,0) \} $ so under $\mathbb R $ the $\ T$ matrx can not be diagonalized. and Under $\ \mathbb C $ we have another two eigen values, $\ i, -i $ so I get this linear equations which I'm not sure how to proceed from here:

$\ (3-i)x =0 \\ (2-i)y -5z = 0 \\ y + (-2-i)z = 0 $

Comment: It has three distinct eigenvalues, so it is diagonalizable (over $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: Proceed just as you would if the eigenvalue were real: solve the system of equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no compelling reason to actually compute a diagonalizing basis for $T$ in order to prove this. $T$ has three distinct eigenvalues, so its characteristic polynomial is also its minimal polynomial. Over $\mathbb C$, this obviously splits into the product of three distinct linear terms, hence $T$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$, but the factor $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb R$, therefore $T$ is not diagonalizable over that field.

If you do need to find eigenvectors for the two complex eigenvalues, proceed as you would if they were real: solve the system of linear equations. The presence of $i$ in the system doesn’t really change the solution method, but you’ll end up with complex solutions.

Comment: A couple of handy facts to know when finding eigenvectors of complex eigenvalues of a real matrix: the eigenvalues come in conjugate pairs, and if $A\mathbf v=\lambda\mathbf v$, then $A\overline{\mathbf v}=\overline\lambda \overline{\mathbf v}$, i.e., corresponding eigenvectors also come in conjugate pairs.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix diagonalizes over $\mathbb{C}$ since it is $3\times 3$ and has three distinct eigenvalues.

As for your three equations, you have $x = 0$.  Now, look at the other two by solving for $y$ in each.  What do you see?

Comment: But what about $\ I $ matrix? It has only one distinct eigenvalue and yet it is diagonalizes, am I right? I need three eigenvectors that are linearly independent for T to be able to be diagonalized, right?

Comment: @YardenGur A $n \times n$ matrix can be diagonalized iff: 1) it has $n$ different eigenvalues; or 2) it has less than $n$ different eigenvalues, but their algebraic multiplicities add up to $n$ and the geometric and algebraic multiplicities of each eigenvalue are equal.

Comment: @YardenGur So the $n \times n$ matrix $\ I$ is diagonalizable because it has one eigenvalue (1) with geometric and algebraic multiplicities equal to $n$